# Selecting Audio Stream in android for music

Tags: android, audio, mediastreamsource

My problem is that I have to play a music file on Voice call stream in android MediaPlayer mySound 
When I run the code for Music stream it is working correctly

```
    MediaPlayer.create(getBaseContext(), R.raw.a );
    mySound.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
    mySound.start();
```

But when I change the stream then the audio does not play.

Comment: What do you mean "change the stream"?

Comment: Well there are about seven streams in android including music, system,voice call, alarm and notifications

Comment: Are you changing the audio stream type to AudioManager.STREAM_VOICE_CALL?

Comment: _"I have to play a music file on Voice call stream in android"_. Are you trying to inject audio into the uplink during a voice call (that's not supported), or are you doing this for some other reason?

Comment: Yes I did it and then no audio is played. I also tried the other 6 streams